# How do I filter out empty value from a form collection?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created the following fieldset which I use in a form collection element. An arbitray amount of URL aliases can be added by the user in a form. It works well but have I have run into a couple of problems.

```
<?php

....

class AliasFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('aliasList');

        $this->setObject(new PathEntity());
        $this->setName('Aliases');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'urn',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text'
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'urn' => array(
                'requried' => false,
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Uri',
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get the Uri validator to allow empty values. Ideally I would like to filter out any empty string items before hand but it appears to me that filters filter the value and are not suitable for filtering out the item itself.

Comment: if you are certain about this ... it may a new bug for zf2 forms ... post it at zend framework JIRA

Comment: Additionally you may be interested in Robs Article "Setting up required fields that can be empty": http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/setting-up-required-fields-that-can-be-empty-with-zendinputfilter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the spelling of 'requried' to 'required'.